# Gas from bacteria that's not methane

Tags: bacteriology

Is gas produced by bacteria always mainly methane? Or, are there bacteria out there that produce some biogas composed mainly of hydrogen, natural gas, propane, butane?

Comment: synthetic biology is working hard to produce such things, but they aren't found naturally in significant quantities I think.

Comment: note that methanogens actually use $H_2$ that is generated by other bacteria.

Comment: Isn't natural gas mainly methane?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microbes can produce several gasses other than methane.

- All microbes produce $CO_2$ through the oxidation of reduced carbon

Additionally some metabolic pathways produce other gases.

- Photosynthetic microbes produce $O_2$
- Sulfur reducing bacteria can produce $H_2S$ (as @ohcanada points out)
- Denitrifying bacteria produce $NO$, $N_2O$, and $N_2$
- Fermenters produce $H_2$ (as @mart indicates)

There may be others that I am not thinking of but these are some of the major players...

Comment: Good answer. Although fermentation can produce carbon dioxide too.

Comment: @JackAidley indeed they do... thanks.  I edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Well, some bacteria can produce Hydrogen Sulfide gas. For example, Proteus and Salmonella. The presence of $H_2S$ producing bacteria is actually clinically significant and we have a way to test for this, which is via the use of TSI (Triple Sugar Iron) media.

Assume you set up the test correctly, $H_2S$ producing bacteria will generate dark deposit within the media.

In the clinical setting, there are other choices beside TSI, such as SIM media and API20E.

Comment: Thanks sviter! This is actually my first time using Stackexchange so I'm still trying to familiarize myself about the word format here.